# Laurent series, radii of convergence.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I'm working on the following exercise:

> Prove that a Laurent series
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_{-n}(z-z_0)^{-n}
> \end{align*}
>   converge for all $z$ such that $r < |z-z_0| < R$, where
>   \begin{align*}
> r = \limsup |a_{-n}|^{1/n}, \quad R^{-1} = \limsup |a_n|^{1/n},
> \end{align*}
>   with $0 \le r$, $R \le \infty$.

I already tried the ratio test, but I didn't find the limit to be $<1$ and also with comparison test I didn't reach a result.
Maybe there is another approach which I don't know.
I wanted to prove the convergence for both parts of the series, because if both parts converge, then also the whole Laurent series.

Thanks.

Comment: This is one of the basic, or even **the** basic, theorem on convergence radius of Laurent Series. Any decent compelx analysis book brings the proof.

Comment: Root test, Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wanted to prove the convergence for both parts of the series, because if both parts converge, then also the whole Laurent series.

This is a very good idea, indeed:

The power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges in the disk $|z-z_0|<R$ where $R$ is given by the Cauchy-Hadamard formula $$R^{-1}= \limsup |a_n|^{1/n} $$

The series of negative terms can be transformed into a power series with positive powers using the substitution $\frac{1}{z-z_0}=w$. The series then becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n} w^n $$ and it converges in the disk $|w|<r$, where, again by Cauchy-Hadamard's formula $r^{-1}=\limsup |a_{-n}|^{1/n}$. Clearly the disk $|w|<r$ is equivalent to the annulus $\left|  \frac{1}{z-z_0}\right|<r$.

Combining the above results, the problem is solved.